# What's the meaning of suffixes that procmail assigns to mail filenames?

Tags: procmail, maildir

I am running a `Postfix` server and I would like to know the meaning of suffixes that mail filenames have. For instance:

```
1338839258.Vfe02I2a6f0M572204.example.com:2,S
1338840057.Vfe02I2a6f1M483134.example.com:2,S
...
```

And also, what's the criteria to assign them? I've been searching information on this topic, but I have only found references to `procmail` mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `2` indicates that each character following the comma is a flag.

The `S` flag means "seen" (i.e. the message has been read).

http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html

Comment: To clarify: this is ***NOT*** a `procmail` (or even `Postfix`) specific thing: It is part of the [`maildir` inbox format, and is supported by a number of MTAs and MDAs (and even used by a few MUAs apparently)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir)

Comment: I know that (hence the link to the Maildir spec).  The OP didn't.

Comment: I know you know that Kevin (because you linked to the spec), I also know the OP didn't (because they asked the question) and don't want them wandering around with a mistaken impression should the link to the spec not be a good enough hint :)

Comment: Fair enough.  In the future, I'll explain to OPs: "This isn't a `foo` issue, it's a `bar` issue, and here's the answer and the `bar` specification."  :-)

Comment: Thanks for this clarifying discussion ^_^ IMHO the first comment should've been made to my post, not the answer.